# Automated Messages in discord.py (discord bot)

Tags: python, automation, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm programming a discord bot which should start some comands including a timer and two surveys every tuesday and thursday at 11.30 am.

Unfortunately the documentary is outdated and older articles in stack overflow do not work anymore. How do I do that in Python or is this impossible? The single commands are already programmed and work without problems.

Comment: What have you tried, and where does it go wrong?

Comment: the full automation. did not find anything and im clueless how to do it.

Comment: You could check out [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/). It probably has what you need

Comment: Hi Dimyyy, this question is *extremely* vague. Could you provide more context? Things like what library you're using (discord.py, pycord, nextcord, etc), how you plan to do the timer, and most importantly: your code! Please provide you're code for what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually , This Option Can't Be Added With `Discord.py` .
You Should Use `Time` Or `Datetime` Modules . 
To Manage Scripts At The Correct Times .

[Check This Article !](https://realpython.com/python-datetime/)

Answer (score 0):

I got my soultion. I worked with apscheduler and now I can time it for days and times.

This can be closed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).